# DTCoreText file not found

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to use `DTCoreText` and I have followed the setup documentation to the T. Everything seems to be working find and my project builds correctly, however, when I try to import some classes to try them out in my view controller I get a file not found.

I didn't make any changes to this project for simplicity its a Single View bare bones template with `DTCoreText` configured to work with it after following the setup instructions on `DTCoreText's` github

I have posted a zipped version of [my project here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/37430783/NativeReader%20iOS/NativeReader.zip):

Is there something I am missing here?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated-

Comment: :S I agree, I was thinking my questions just weren't worthy or something. Is it possible to go back and accept answers that helped me in the past? 

Usually nobody has been able to field my answers so I never accepted any

Comment: You can go back and accept at least a few of them which was helpful.

Comment: Could you explain what the issue was @Adam?

Comment: Yes the problem actually existed in my "Other linker flags" in my build settings for my application target. 

What you must be sure of a few things specfically the paths you set for your header and user search paths.

Header search paths should be: /usr/include/libxml2

and for me the "user header search paths" are: /Users/yourusername/projectdirectory/yourproject/Externals <- set to recursive

and so for you the user header search path would have been from root to your project Externals directory set to recursive. Just to be clear :) Let me know if this helps!

Comment: However I had found that the DTCoreText library is not usable nor user friendly. There is 0 documentation on the project and its like walking through a dark forest. So know that you may never come out-